# Selective Bloom is not Working in react three fiber

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

[image]

here is the code in codesandbox .I want to give bloom effect on two models

Comment: Can you provide a link to codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/selective-bloom-yqrm3?file=/src/App.js:0-1510

Comment: I haven't forked yet.. I have edited this as you can see in the image .I have omitted all rotation and hover effects. .I just want to give two model bloom effect. help me if you can